# Print or return string from a for loop

Tags: r

Here is the question- Build a condition to check if all the numbers in the vector marks(passed as argumemts) are greater than 90. If yes, assign the string "Best Class" to the variable ans ,else assign "Needs Improvement".

This is the code i have written-

```
classmark<-function(marks){
 ans<- marks
 for(i in 1:length(marks)){
 if(marks[i] > 90){
         cat("Best Class")
     }
     else{
         cat("Needs Improvement")
     }
}    
return(ans)
}
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,56)))
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,96)))
```

Actual Output -

```
Best Class Best Class Best Class Needs Improvement
Best Class Best Class Best Class Best Class
```

Output that i got -

```
Best Class Best Class Best Class Needs Improvement[1] 100 95 94 56
Best Class Best Class Best Class Best Class[1] 100 95 94 96
```

suggest any changes that need to modify in the code to get the actual output

Comment: Don't use `cat` in R. That's a bad habit to develop. If you want to create functions that print diagnostic messages, use the `message` function. Also, generally, functions should have a proper (and useful) return value (like @Ronak's second suggestion) and not just print the main result.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to print in the loop, remove the `return` statement from the function.

```
classmark<-function(marks){
  ans<- marks
  for(i in 1:length(marks)){
    if(marks[i] > 90){
      cat("Best Class\n")
    }
    else{
      cat("Needs Improvement\n")
    }
  }    
}

classmark(c(100,95,94,56))
#Best Class
#Best Class
#Best Class
#Needs Improvement
```

You can also use a vectorised version with `ifelse` which does not require `for` loop.

```
classmark<-function(marks){
 ifelse(marks > 90, "Best Class", "Needs Improvement")
}

classmark(c(100,95,94,56))
#[1] "Best Class"   "Best Class"   "Best Class"    "Needs Improvement"
```

Comment: It doesn't work for both your answers, let explore the if else solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition is to check if "all" the numbers:

```
classmark <- function(marks) { 
  ans <- c() 
  for (i in 1:length(marks)) {
    if (marks[i] > 90) { 
      ans <- "Best Class"
    } else { 
      ans <- "Needs Improvement" 
    } 
  } 
  return(ans) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this Works or not.

```
filter <- marks > 90
x <- TRUE
for (y in filter){
    x <- x && y
}
if(x){
    ans <- "Best Class"
}else{
    ans <- "Needs Improvement"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually asking to check if all values of parameter (marks) are above 90, not individual values.

```
classmark<-function(marks){

  # Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
  
  # if all values in marks are greater than 90, return "Best Class"
  if (all(marks > 90)){
    return ("Best Class")
  }
  else {
    return ("Needs Improvement")
  }  
}
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,56)))
print(classmark(c(100,95,94,96)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
for(i in 1:length(marks)){
    if(marks[i]>90){
        ans<- "Best Class"
    }
    else{
        ans<- "Needs Improvement"
    }
}

return(ans)
```